# Excel Macros: Checking Data and coloring using excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Column "C"  in sheet2 which can have 3 standard values say (Yes, No, NA) say till 100th row. Now in Sheet1 column G5 & G6, I want to output the result based on following conditions. Condition1- If all the values in Sheet2 Column C is Yes/NA then Output value should be YES in G5 with background green color and if any NO is present value should be NO and Red Colour in G6. 
Condition2- If all the values in Sheet2 Column C is No/NA then Output value should be NO in G6 with background Red color.

Comment: The two steps are to figure out a formula - try `COUNTIFS` - to calculate the "Yes" or "No" part and then apply Conditional Formatting to that cell. No VBA required.

Comment: Can you put across the formula please for the above mentioned criteria and where should I put that formula. Sorry I am not familiar with Excel formula and Conditional formatting.

Comment: @DougGlancy: Can you please elaborate and help me please.

Comment: @DougGlancy: We can only find true condition using COUNTIFS. I mean only YES, what if NO is present in that column. How to make a decission over here? I want to know whether only YES or any NO is present in that column. Then give out the output. I have edited my question accordingly. Please refer once more.

Comment: @sandesh:  What if there are both **Yes**  and  **No** in the column and none of the Conditions are true??

Comment: That's incorrect. You can count YESes, NOs and NAs. Sorry, I don't have time for more now.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: If none of the conditions are true, leave it Blank or as it is. I don't want any changes to be done there.

Comment: @DougGlancy- are you sure it can be done only using COUNTIFS and Conditional Formatting? If so I will give a hard try to do it. Are you sure Glancy?

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I am getting Run Time Error 9; Subscript out of range Error. Debug:Pointing to row - Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1"). Thanks for your help buddy.

Comment: @sandesh:  Means there is a typo in the sheet name.  Check for "Sheet1" v.s. "Sheet 1", etc.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: I corrected that. But issue now is If all the fields are blank even then its giving Yes with Green instead of leaving it Blank.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: Its working fine but when there is neither YES nor NO its not giving blank value, I tried adding loop to keep Field value blank but not successful. Please help.

Comment: Please re-check......I get blanks in both G5 and G6  if neither condition is true.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent: First one is working better than the second. I really thank your friend as well for his idea. Any improvisation on first one for Blanks could definitely work. Till this way Thank you so much buddy. Value 100 is not working with me, not sure why? any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Sub YesNoCheck()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim rCheck As Range
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rCheck = s2.Range("C1:C100")
    s1.Range("G5:G6").Clear
    If wf.CountIf(rCheck, "No") = 0 Then
        s1.Range("G5").Value = "Yes"
        s1.Range("G5").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If wf.CountIf(rCheck, "Yes") = 0 Then
        s1.Range("G6").Value = "No"
        s1.Range("G6").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1**

My error, use this instead:

```
Sub YesNoCheck2()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim rCheck As Range
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set rCheck = s2.Range("C1:C100")
    s1.Range("G5:G6").Clear
    If wf.CountIf(rCheck, "Yes") + wf.CountIf(rCheck, "NA") = 100 Then
        s1.Range("G5").Value = "Yes"
        s1.Range("G5").Interior.ColorIndex = 10
    End If
    If wf.CountIf(rCheck, "No") + wf.CountIf(rCheck, "NA") = 100 Then
        s1.Range("G6").Value = "No"
        s1.Range("G6").Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End Sub
```

A friend looking over my shoulder pointed out that if all the entries are "NA", then both conditions could be true!!